# HtmlAgilityPack - Get DIV content

Tags: c#, html, string, html-agility-pack, scrape

I am trying to get some text out of a DIV with HtmlAgilityPack in WinForms C#.

My code is:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("http://www.tibia.com/news/?subtopic=latestnews");
var res = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='PlayersOnline']");
var content = res.InnerHtml;

// Print content
MessageBox.Show(content);
```

The content I am trying to get is from:
http://www.tibia.com/news/?subtopic=latestnews

At the top-right of the website there is a box that says the amount of "Players Online". I want to get that amount.

The HTML on the website looks like this:

```
<div id="PlayersOnline" onclick="window.location = 'https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds';">11723<br>Players Online</div>
```

So I want to get `11723` as output. It wouldn't matter if i get the entire: `11723<br>Players Online` as output. i could just regex match later on or split string or something, to ignore the br tag.

But none of my code is working and i don't know why. the application crashes and says

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

<res>5__8 was null.
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this rows:

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.Web webSite = new HtmlAgilityPack.Web();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = webSite.Load("http://www.tibia.com/news/?subtopic=latestnews");

    string content = document.GetElementbyId("PlayersOnline").OuterHtml;
```

Comment: Gave me this error: `System.ArgumentException: 'URI formats are not supported.'`

Comment: Sory.. HtmlWeb website = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = website.Load("yourUrl");

Comment: Application just crashes and says `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.GetElementbyId(...) returned null.`

Answer (score 1):

Try `InnerText` instead of `InnerHtml`

```
var content = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='PlayersOnline']").InnerText;
```

Comment: Can you try by adding a dot in front of //div.

Comment: Something like doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id='PlayersOnline']").InnerText;