# HtmlAgilityPack equivalent to webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rd0").InnerHtml;

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

When I use `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rd0").InnerHtml`, I get
`<div style="color:rgb(138,66,0)">69.8 F </div></td>` 
which I then split to get just 69.8 F

I am having trouble when trying to use  HtmlAgilityPack. I can’t seem to drill down to the element to capture the 69.8 F

What is the HtmlAgilityPack equivalent to webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rd0").InnerHtml; so that I can capture just the value of the element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078396/34092

Comment: I get <tr>
  <td name="lb0" id="lb0"></td>
  <td name="rd0" id="rd0"></td>
 </tr> when I do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rd0").InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use webBrowser. I want to use HtmlAgilityPack.